# Quartz.net with Oracle JobStore

Tags: .net, .net-core, quartz.net

Quartz.Net not saving the job/trigger info to Oracle tables when I use xml plugin.

I have read other posts and tried both "quartz_jobs.xml" and "~\quartz_jobs.xml" for the "quartz.plugin.jobInitializer.fileNames" property;

The Code executes fine, I don't see any exceptions. I see data in the QRTZ_LOCKS & QRTZ_SCJEDULER_STATE tables but the QRTZ_CRON_TRIGGERS, QRTZ_JOB_DETAILS tables are empty.

Not sure why it won't save the job/trigger info.

Please help!

Here's the code:

```
private async Task ScheduleJob(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{
    try
    {
        var props = GetQuartzSettings();
        var factory = new StdSchedulerFactory(props);
        var scheduler = await factory.GetScheduler();
        scheduler.JobFactory = new FunctionServiceJobFactory(serviceProvider);
        await scheduler.Start();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _log.LogError(ex, "Exception faced in ScheduleJob()");
    }
}

private NameValueCollection GetQuartzSettings() =>
    new NameValueCollection
    {
        ["quartz.serializer.type"] = "json",
        ["quartz.scheduler.instanceName"] = "TEST1",
        ["quartz.scheduler.instanceId"] = "AUTO",
        ["quartz.threadPool.type"] = "Quartz.Simpl.SimpleThreadPool, Quartz",
        ["quartz.threadPool.threadCount"] = "10",
        ["quartz.threadPool.threadPriority"] = "Normal",
        ["quartz.jobStore.type"] = "Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.JobStoreTX, Quartz",
        ["quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateType"] = "Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.OracleDelegate, Quartz",
        ["quartz.jobStore.useProperties"] = "false",
        ["quartz.jobStore.dataSource"] = "default",
        ["quartz.dataSource.default.provider"] = "OracleODPManaged",
        ["quartz.dataSource.default.connectionString"] = "ConnectionString",
        ["quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix"] = "QRTZ_",
        ["quartz.plugin.jobInitializer.type"] = "Quartz.Plugin.Xml.XMLSchedulingDataProcessorPlugin, Quartz.Plugins",
        ["quartz.plugin.jobInitializer.failOnFileNotFound"] = "true",
        ["quartz.plugin.jobInitializer.fileNames"] = "~\\quartz_jobs.xml",
        ["quartz.plugin.jobInitializer.ScanInterval"] = "0"
    };
```

Here is the content of quartz_jobs.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<job-scheduling-data xmlns="http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/JobSchedulingData" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.0">
  <schedule>
    <job>
      <name>DEPTH</name>
      <group>TENSECONDS</group>
      <description>Data Service</description>
      <job-type>DataService.Job.FunctionServiceJob, DataService.Job</job-type>
      <job-data-map>
        <entry>
          <key>Id</key>
          <value>DEPTH23</value>
        </entry>
      </job-data-map>
    </job>
    <trigger>
      <cron>
        <name>TENSECONDSTrigger</name>
        <group>TENSECONDSTriggerGroup</group>
        <job-name>DEPTH</job-name>
        <job-group>TENSECONDS</job-group>
        <misfire-instruction>DoNothing</misfire-instruction>
        <cron-expression>0/10 0/1 0 ? * * *</cron-expression>
      </cron>
    </trigger>
  </schedule>
</job-scheduling-data>
```

I am using .Net Core 3.1 Console Application and Quartz.Net version is 3.2.4

I have similar set up that works with SQL Server but for some reason I am not able to make it write to Oracle.

Comment: Enabling logging usually helps understanding what is happening.

Comment: Thank you Marko Lahma. I was able to fix the issue after enabling console logging.